# Angular : ng-select does not show ng-selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

Trying to set the default value in select depending on the id.

I have a object `location` where `<pre>{{location.routeId}}</pre>` prints an id `819e41ef-0081-41e6-a415-2766dc16e8e4`

```
<select ng-model="location.route">
        <option value="" disabled>Choose Route</option>
        <option ng-repeat="route in appData.Routes" 
             ng-selected="{{route.id == location.routeId}}" 
             value="{{route}}">
             {{route.id}} : {{route.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

The `route` in`appData.Routes` has parameters `name` and `id`, I'm trying to match `route.id` with `location.routeId`

If I inspect element, I can see`ng-selected` as true for one of the options, but still its not being selected in the UI.

[image]

And here is the screenshot of UI

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Take out the disabled attribute in your first option.

Comment: That did not help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="location.route">
        <option value="">Choose Route</option>
        <option ng-repeat="route in appData.Routes" 
             ng-selected="route.id == location.routeId || location.route && route.id == location.route.id" 
             ng-value="route">
             {{route.id}} : {{route.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Basically I need to return the complete `route`object which has `name` and `id`. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: @DeepakBandi check updates

Comment: It selected the first option right now. `<option style="display:none;" value="" class="" selected="selected">Choose Route</option>` How do I get the right id selected?

Comment: @DeepakBandi Check again plz.

Comment: Sorry @MeTe-30, still no luck. 

`<option ng-repeat="route in appData.Routes" ng-selected="route.id == location.routeId || location.route &amp;&amp; route.id == location.route.id" ng-value="route" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="
                                 5fe75e95-d281-4e55-b259-5202f3dd0c5a : Jimmy
                            " selected="selected">
                                 5fe75e95-d281-4e55-b259-5202f3dd0c5a : Jimmy
                            </option>`

Comment: That's what it is printing in the console. It shows as selected, but still shows Choose Route as default.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need curly braces for ngSelected directive. So simply remove them:

```
ng-selected="{{route.id == location.routeId}}"
```

To:

```
ng-selected="route.id == location.routeId"
```

Comment: That did not help.

Comment: can you create a plunker? @DeepakBandi