# AngularJS: ng-selected doesn't show selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As on the title my select doesn't seem able to show the selected value, that is for instance, correctly selected...

```
<md-input-container flex>
    <label>Anno selezione</label>
    <md-select name="annoSelect" ng-model="vm.anno_attuale"
               ng-value="vm.progetto.pprs[$index].anno"
               ng-selected="item.selected" >
         <md-option ng-repeat="item in vm.progetto.pprs" >
           {{vm.progetto.pprs[$index].anno}}
         </md-option>
    </md-select> 
</md-input-container>
```

I tried with some solutions found on stack, such as that one:
[Angular : ng-select does not show ng-selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796338/angular-ng-select-does-not-show-ng-selected-value)

but any of them didn't fix the issue...
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

From the Docs:

> Note: `ngSelected` does not interact with the `select` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the `selected` attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the select, you should not use `ngSelected` on the options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-selected Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

The `ng-value` directive is in the wrong place:

```
<md-input-container flex>
    <label>Anno selezione</label>
    <md-select name="annoSelect" ng-model="vm.anno_attuale"
               ̶n̶g̶-̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶v̶m̶.̶p̶r̶o̶g̶e̶t̶t̶o̶.̶p̶p̶r̶s̶[̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶]̶.̶a̶n̶n̶o̶"̶                 
               ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶=̶"̶i̶t̶e̶m̶.̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶"̶ ̶  >
         <md-option ng-repeat="item in vm.progetto.pprs" 
                    ng-value="item.anno">
           ̶{̶{̶v̶m̶.̶p̶r̶o̶g̶e̶t̶t̶o̶.̶p̶p̶r̶s̶[̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶]̶.̶a̶n̶n̶o̶}̶}̶
           {{item.anno}}
         </md-option>
    </md-select> 
</md-input-container>
```

For more information, see [Using `ngValue` to bind the model to an array of objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)

Comment: OOOOH yesss... you're a real magician!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move The `ng-selected` from the `<select>` element to the `<option>` element

> The ng-selected directive sets the selected attribute of an `<option>` element in a `<select>` list.

[ng-selected - AngularJS Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

In your particular case it appears you have more than one problem going on in your code. `ng-value` and `ng-selected` directives belong with the `<md-options>` element. Also you need to choose a strategy, if you use `ng-model` and `ng-value` then you shouldn't use `ng-selected`.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<md-input-container flex>
<label>Anno selezione</label>
<md-select name="annoSelect" ng-model="vm.anno_attuale">
<md-option ng-repeat="item in vm.progetto.pprs" ng-value="vm.progetto.pprs[$index].anno">{{vm.progetto.pprs[$index].anno}}</md-option>
</md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Also I would double check your `ng-model` and `ng-value` to make sure you're getting the values you think you are. Take a look here at the official [AngularJS Material mdSelect Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect). There is an example very similar to yours. It should help get you on your way!

Comment: Thanks!
Sounds good... but doesn't seem to work, anyway...
Maybe tem.selected is note the correct value for my ng-selected?

Comment: See updated answer, @Miss-Take.